# Multiple Email Addresses for Form Submission

Tags: php, forms, email

I have two scenarios for my form that will determine if the submission is successful or failed. Either outcome serves the user with a unique page. I am looking for a way that the successful submissions are emailed to group A email addresses and the failed submissions are sent to Group B email addresses.

Here is my code:

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {



$from=$_POST['empty'];
$to=$_POST['empty'];
$subject=$_POST['empty'];
$text=$_POST['empty'];
$html=$_POST['empty'];
$file=$_POST['empty'];
$mimetype=$_POST['empty'];
$host=$_POST['empty'];
$username=$_POST['empty'];
$password=$_POST['empty'];

$Q1=$_POST['Q1'];
$Q2=$_POST['Q2'];
$Q3=$_POST['Q3'];
$Q4=$_POST['Q4'];

$fromsubject = 'sample-subject';
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber']; 

$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 

    $header = "From: <" . $mail . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields
$mailsubject = 'Message recived from  sample site';
$body = $fromsubject.'

The person that contacted you is  '.$firstname.'
 Phone number: '.$phonenumber.'
 E-mail: '.$mail.'
 Q1: '.$Q1.'
 Q2: '.$Q2.'
 Q3: '.$Q3.'
 Q4: '.$Q4.'



|---------END MESSAGE----------|';

mail($to, $mailsubject, $body, $header);
if ($Q3 == "yes") {
header('Location: http://example.com/success.php');
} else {
header('Location: http://example.com/resources.php');
}




?>
```

Comment: what is *successful* vs *failed* submissions ? what does *emailed to group A|B email addresses* mean?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. My form has 4 questions in it. If they answer no to one of them, they do not qualify for our offer. If they answer yes to all, they qualify. The all yes users need to be sent to our call center email address while the other respondents who did not answer all yes go to our recovery department.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the confusion. My form has 4 questions in it. If they answer no to one of them, they do not qualify for our offer. If they answer yes to all, they qualify. The all yes users need to be sent to our call center email address while the other respondents who did not answer all yes go to our recovery department. –